# ¿Consecuencias al no usar punto y coma al final de mysql queries en PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Tuve algunas mezclas de datos en mi tabla de mysql y estoy pensando si eso sería debido a falta de algunos puntos y comas al final de mis queries. Digamos que tengo este código:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM customers_2016 WHERE customer_db_id = ? ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
            $customer_db_id,
        )
    );

$sql = "UPDATE customers_2016
SET valor = 1
WHERE customer_db_id = ? ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
            $customer_db_id,
        )
    );
```

Podría obtener errores si ejecutara ese código sin puntos y comas al final de la query cientos de veces cada día?

Comment: En php no son necesarias dado que se usa para ejecutar multiples querys y en php eso no es posible con un solo execute, de hecho si tu pones $sql = "select * from usuario;  update usuario set campo = 3;" no te va a ejecutar ambas, debes poner que mezcla te paso para ver cual puede ser el problema

Comment: @Sergio1871 Sergio puedes poner tu comentario como respuesta ?

Comment: Omitir el `;` en la cadena de consulta cuando el mismo es requerido **es una mala práctica de programación**, además ¿cuál es el motivo para no ponerlo?.

Comment: ¿Es PHP? Creo que falta la etiqueta de [tag:php] o se sobre entiende por la de [tag:pdo]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para responder a tu pregunta:
El punto y coma es parte de la [definición de consulta que hace MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/entering-queries.html):

> A query normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a semicolon.
>   (There are some exceptions where a semicolon may be omitted. QUIT,
>   mentioned earlier, is one of them. We'll get to others later.)
>
> ---
>
> Una consulta normalmente consiste en una sentencia SQL **seguida de un
>   punto y coma.** (Hay algunas excepciones en las que se puede omitir un
>   punto y coma, QUIT, mencionado anteriormente, es uno de ellos.

Es posible que en PHP no tengas problemas si omites el `;` al final de las consultas, pues en el caso de tu ejemplo envías consultas preparadas que separan la sentencia SQL de los datos que envían.

Supongo, y, sería interesante investigarlo, que PDO o MySQLi, en caso de que omitas el `;` en la cadena SQL que envías, lo proveen en tu lugar.

**Pero, yo nunca delegaría en el programa algo que debo hacer yo.** ¿Por qué construir una consulta sin basarme en las normas establecidas por el manejador de base de datos que estoy usando? No puedo en ese sentido ser un programador aventurero, y mucho menos si se trata de un manejo de datos (`UPDATE... DELETE`). Aunque la posibilidad de error omitiendo el `;` sea mínima o ninguna, en este caso... quien sabe, te puedes llevar una sorpresa desagradable.

Si consideramos el mismo uso en línea de comando veremos rápidamente que podría haber problemas al omitir el `;`, afectar el rendimiento de MySQL o provocar algún otro error.

Lo siguiente está tomado de la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/entering-queries.html):

> Multiple-line statements commonly occur by accident when you intend to
>   issue a query on a single line, but forget the terminating semicolon.
>   In this case, mysql waits for more input:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT USER()
> ->
> ```
>
> If this happens to you (you think you've entered a statement but the only response is a -> prompt), most likely mysql is waiting
>   for the semicolon. If you don't notice what the prompt is telling you,
>   you might sit there for a while before realizing what you need to do.
>   Enter a semicolon to complete the statement, and mysql executes it:

---

> Las sentencias de varias líneas comúnmente ocurren por accidente
>   cuando se tiene la intención de emitir una consulta en una sola línea,
>   pero **se olvida del punto y coma final. En este caso, mysql espera más
>   información**:
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT USER()
> ->
> ```
>
> Si esto te sucede (**piensas que has ingresado una sentencia, pero la única respuesta es un prompt** `->`), **lo más probable es que mysql esté esperando el punto y coma**. Si usted no nota lo que le está diciendo, usted puede sentarse allí por un tiempo antes de realizar lo que usted necesita hacer. Introduzca un punto y coma para completar la sentencia y mysql lo ejecuta.

### Conclusión

Punto y coma ¡**siempre en las consultas que lo requieran (`SELECT... UPDATE... DELETE... INSERT...` y otras)**

No hay excusa para no usarlo.

Comment: Bravo ! Eso es lo que explica perfectamente mi pregunta... Menuda respuesta mas documentada .. Me sirve de mucho, gracias y voy a corregir mis codigos. La unica razon por la que no lo he utilizado es el olvido por pensar que no es de necesidad.

Answer (score 2):

En php no son necesarias dado que se usa para ejecutar múltiples querys y en php eso no es posible con un solo execute, de hecho si tu pones...

```
$sql = "select * from usuario; update usuario set campo = 3;"
```

No te va a ejecutar ambas, debes poner que mezcla te pasó para ver cual puede ser el problema.